# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/mrpravin21/Documents/Python3/Application6/users.json' ( kivy app )

Tags: python, android, linux, kivy

I am trying to build a simple kivy mobile app and i has sucessfully created the apk file using buildozer.
Whenever i opened the app in the mobile the app used to crash in about 2 seconds so i read the logcat and fixed the error.
This app of mine has a login interface and it stores the login credentials in a json file. Now whenever i try to login or sign up the app crashes again so it has no functionality as i can only view the home screen.
I read the logs and i got this error message

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/mrpravin21/Documents/Python3/Application6/users.json'
```

So i looked in the buildozer specs file to see where i can mention the json file but i could not find anything.
So please help me out here!

Comment: Yes that is an impossible path for an Android device. No wonder that to the .json file could not be found.

Comment: `'/home/mrpravin21/Documents/Python3/Application6/users.json'` the error is exactly what it says, there is no such directoy in the mobile device. The solution would be to store the login file relative to the file path inside the device.

Comment: Please add a [mre] to your post showing your login code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try removing setup.py from buildozer folder....that worked for me

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31526505)